# How to load a specific class name on only first active UI react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

wanted to load a class name "Landingpage" to body tag or main container div  only if the first tab/section (Overview page) is active. tab sections are in a child component.
Please help

https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-router-ui-cvdzpe?file=/src/DatavisualizationAll.js

https://cvdzpe.csb.app/SubpageLanding/Datavisualization

```
function Datavisualization(props) {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("tab1");
  const isActive = (key) => (active === key ? "active" : "");
```

Comment: `Landing page` is like 2 class names, you should double check your question

Answer (score 2):

```
className={active === "tab1" ? "landing-page" : ""}
```

kindly add some character in your class name "Landing Page" or remove space otherwise class will not work.

Comment: I wanted to load a class name 'landing-page'  on body tag or Main page container eg: <div class="p-0 py-3 containerMain container-fluid"> if the first/tab1 is active /loaded  . new class name not required to load in active tab item.

Comment: Also the Tabs and tab content is in a different child component